# Trigger function just before jquery.validate() validates form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, function

I have a form that on submit jquery.validate() validates the form and if this fails the form won't be submitted. Now I want that just before the form is validated a function is triggered. My idea was that there should be some type of 'beforeValidate' paramater or something like that in the .validate() just like rules, messages etc...

Answer (score 0):

If i got ur question correctly i think this is what u need to do (somehow)

```
$(".selector").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
      var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
      if (errors) {
        var message = errors == 1
          ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
          : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
        $("div.error span").html(message);
        $("div.error").show();
      } else {
        $("div.error").hide();
      }
    }
 })
```

More modification can be done in this code, but without code supply this can be consider as a template ;)